# Most efficient way to zoom in data, realign y axis scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a large timeseries dataset, plotting (3,1,x) sublots, all plotted against the same timestamps. As the data is quite large, to analyse I need to "zoom-in" on portions and compare the three graphs on a micro level.

I figured that the easiest way is to initially plot the full dataset, and then use the xlim function, on each subplot, in order to see only the portion of interest. The issue is that the y-axis scale, on a "zoomed" graph is completely out of proportion.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to auto readjust the y-axis, based on the y values corresponding to the xlim part of the data? .autoscale won't work when using xlim, it basically removes the xlim and plots the full set of data.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
ax1.plot(xaxis, e)
ax2.plot(xaxis, y, 'b-', label = "y")
ax2.plot(xaxis, yhat, 'm--', label = "yhat") 
ax3.plot(xaxis, yraw, label = target)
ax1.set_xlim(start,end) 
ax2.set_xlim(start,end)
ax3.set_xlim(start,end)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Would `plt.axis('equal')` help you any?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you can't just plot the portion you care about?

Comment: Finally, please post some sample code that adequately illustrates the issue.

Comment: i) plt.axis('equal') doesnt seem to return to appropriate scale
ii) creating 1 plot with all the data, and just changing the limits has the advantage of not having to create a new plot from scratch every time
iii) code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the easiest way to zoom in on data is the [interactive zoom tool](http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html). In a jupyter notebook you get it by showing the figure via `plt.show()` without inline magic. You also get it by using the `%matplotlib notebook` magic.

To make sure all subplots share the same scaling, you can [share the axes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html) using the `sharex` and `sharey` properties.

[image]

Comment: this is useful to know however there are two issues: i) i need all 3 subplots to display the same fraction of the dataset ii) this does not solve the scaling issue.

Comment: I edited the answer for issue (i). But I haven't actually understood *the scaling issue*. Using the rectangle you can determine the scaling in both directions with your mouse.

Comment: The scaling issue is that, the max - min y value range, on the full data is significantly larger than the man - min range on zoomed in data. Therefore ideally I wanted the y-axis to rescale to that smaller range, when analysing on a micro level.

Anyway your suggestion is good enough, as I can see the exact points when moving the pointer. Many thanks for this.